# pythonrc in interactive code

Tags: python, shell

I have a .pythonrc in my path, which gets loaded when I run python:

```
python
Loading pythonrc
>>>
```

The problem is that my .pythonrc is not loaded when I execute files:

```
python -i script.py
>>>
```

It would be very handy to have tab completion (and a few other things) when I load things interactively.

Answer (score 4):

From the Python [documentation for `-i`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i):

> When a script is passed as first argument or the *-c* option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even when `sys.stdin` does not appear to be a terminal. The PYTHONSTARTUP file is not read.

I believe this is done so that scripts run predictably for all users, and do not depend on anything in a user's particular PYTHONSTARTUP file.

Comment: Thanks. I realise this is good default behaviour, but would like to know if it can be circumvented. I suppose I can just add execfile("~/.pythonrc") to my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg has noted, there is a very good reason why `-i` behaves the way it does. However, I do find it pretty useful to be able to have my `PYTHONSTARTUP` loaded when I want an interactive session. So, here's the code I use when I want to be able to have `PYTHONSTARTUP` active in a script run with `-i`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #do normal stuff
    #and at the end of the file:
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive==1:
       import os
       myPythonPath = os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'].split(os.sep)
       sys.path.append(os.sep.join(myPythonPath[:-1]))
       pythonrcName = ''.join(myPythonPath[-1].split('.')[:-1]) #the filename minus the trailing extension, if the extension exists
       pythonrc = __import__(pythonrcName)
       for attr in dir(pythonrc):
           __builtins__.__dict__[attr] = getattr(pythonrc, attr)

       sys.path.remove(os.sep.join(myPythonPath[:-1]))
       del sys, os, pythonrc
```

Note that this is fairly hacky and I *never* do this without ensuring that my pythonrc isn't accidentally clobbering variables and builtins.

Comment: Note: Won't work if your Python file begins with a '.' e.g. `.pythonrc`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the [user module](http://docs.python.org/library/user.html) provides this, but has been removed in Python 3.0. It is a bit of a security hole, depending what's in your pythonrc...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chinmay Kanchi and Greg Hewgill's answers, I'd like to add that IPython and BPython work fine in this case. Perhaps it's time for you to switch? :)