# pythonstartup profile does not work

Tags: python

Most of my work with python uses almost the same modules as well as default settings so I want to do this once for all.
This is what I did:
1. put export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc into ~/.bashrc file
2. put the following code into the /.pythonrc file

```
    from pylab import *
    import os
    rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
    rc('text', usetex=True)
```

However, when I run the following code
python3 test.py
with the test.py containing the simple code like this:

```
    os.chdir('/Users/username/Documents/python/test/')
    datadax=loadtxt('py_dax.txt')
    datashaxn=loadtxt('py_shaxn.txt')
    datashaxw=loadtxt('py_shaxw.txt')
```

It gives me the error: NameError: name 'os' is not defined

I am not sure which step I did wrong.

Comment: What gives expanded `$HOME`, and `/.pythonrc` is different from `./pythonrc`.

Comment: @stovfl sorry this is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is only possible ***in interactive mode***!

> From the Python » Documentation: [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)
>
> If this is the name of a readable file,
>      the Python commands in that file are executed before the first prompt is displayed **in interactive mode**.

Relevant: [SO pythonrc in interactive code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4136550/7414759)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed you are right. However, I also tired the interactive way. I typed python(3) in the terminal and I tried the command 'os.chdir('/Users/username/Documents/python/test/')'. The same error appears. Also I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this when I execute the whole *.py profile.